# PHP xdebug auto_trace enabled causes "Not yet implemented" errors

Tags: xdebug, symfony, php-7

## Setting

I'm running symfony 3.0.2 on PHP Version `7.0.3` in a [CentOS 6 docker container](https://github.com/guytenaerefe/centos6-php7-xdebug/blob/master/web/Dockerfile). When I try to access the index page, I get the following error/warning in the `error_log`, which I don't really understand:

```
PHP Warning:  DOMElement::setAttribute(): Not yet implemented in  <path>/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Loader/XmlFileLoader.php on line 304
```

When I run `php bin/console server:start` or even `php bin/console --version` from the cli I get the following output:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]  
  Warning: DOMElement::setAttribute(): Not yet implemented
```

In the `xdebug.ini` that gets loaded in this docker container, `xdebug.auto_trace = 1` seems to be the issue. Setting it to `0` or removing it (default = 0) solves it.

From the xdebug docs:

> xdebug.auto_trace
>   Type: boolean, Default value: 0
>   When this setting is set to on, the tracing of function calls will be enabled just before the script is run. This makes it possible to trace code in the [auto_prepend_file](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file).

Similar problem, *without explanation* (Helped solving this): http://www.phpdocx.com/en/forum/default/topic/985#post_3587

## Question

Could anybody please explain how these errors are caused (by presumably [auto_prepend_file](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file))?

Comment: so how exactly you fixed this? i tried auto_trace both on and off

Comment: For me, "In the xdebug.ini that gets loaded in this docker container, xdebug.auto_trace = 1 seems to be the issue. Setting it to 0 or removing it (default = 0) solves it." did it.